# Прошу объяснить работу тернарного оператора при обходе массива

Tags: javascript

Я не понимаю, что происходит в условии:

```
acc[item] = acc[item]
```

это значит, если значение acc[item] присвоится значению acc[item], значит возвращаем acc[item] + 1  - правильно?

```
const numbers = [4, 3, 3, 1, 15, 7, 4]; 
    
const countItems = numbers.reduce((acc, item) => {
      acc[item] = acc[item] ? acc[item] + 1 : 1;
      return acc;
    }, {});
```

Comment: Ты неправильно читаешь. `a = a ? a + 1 : 1` надо читать как `a = (a ? (a + 1) : 1)`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: А разве оператор присваивания не имеет более высокий приоритет, чем тернарный? И как понять в таких случаях, где граница условия тернарного оператора? От знака вопроса влево до следующего оператора?

Comment: По ссылке выше всё написано

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном фрагменте `acc[item] = acc[item] ? acc[item] + 1 : 1;` оператор присваивания срабатывает в последнюю очередь. Всё, что находится справа от оператора присваивания, имеет более высокий приоритет и выполняется в первую очередь. А справа у вас обычное условие. И от того, что это условие вернёт, зависит что присвоится в `acc[item]`.

Ваш код это то же самое, что и вот этот:

```
const numbers = [4, 3, 3, 1, 15, 7, 4]

const countItems = numbers.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if (acc[item]) {
        acc[item] = acc[item] + 1
    } else {
        acc[item] = 1
    }
    return acc
}, {})
```

Comment: То есть, сколько бы не было операторов справа от присваивания, сначала оно все выполняется, и только потом происходит присваивание?

Comment: Всё верно. Сначала выполнится выражение справа, в вашем случае это условие, потом результат присвоится левой части.